# Prevent duplicate value insert in database and in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, validation

I want to prevent duplicate roll no entered in database with following code but it is not helpful and also suggest that how to prevent this in gridview also.

```
   If txtRollNo.Text.Trim = "" Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtRollNo, "Roll Number is required")
        Errorcheck = False
      ElseIf varDuplicate = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate values are not allowed")
      Else
       ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtRollNo, "")
  End If


    Private Function Duplicate() As Boolean
        Duplicate = True
        duplicatedata = "Select Count(RollNo) from KaiyumVbStudent where RollNO = &txtRollNo.Text.Trim"
        con = New SqlConnection(constring)
        cmd = New SqlCommand(duplicatedata, con)
        con.Open()
        Dim mcount As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        If mcount > 0 Then
            Duplicate = True
        Else
            Duplicate = False
        End If
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better practice to add a UNIQUE INDEX on the `RollNO` column in the database
and catch the exception and handle that exception in case of duplicate value.

**EDIT** You haven't mentioned your database vendor so here's how to create unique index in SQL SERVER http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187019.aspx

and here's standard SQL

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name)
```

**EDIT 2** besides UNIQUE INDEX, maybe the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT should have been also mentioned http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp. To make sure I do not confuse OP, UNIQUE INDEX and UNIQUE CONSTRAINT are basically the same, they achieve the same goal, their performance is the same; technically there is unique index behind the unique constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column_name)
```

Comment: The UNIQUE INDEX will prevent the creation of duplicate RollNOs from the gridview as well.